# How do I hide an Agular component on all routes that correspond to a certain pattern?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

I am working on an e-commerce app who's front-end is made in Angular 13.

The UI has a sidebar which I do *not* want to display on the *product details* page.

For this purpose, in `app\app.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'E-commerce';
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  /**
   * Check if the router url contains the specified route
   *
   * @param {string} route
   * @returns
   * @memberof AppComponent
   */
   hasRoute(route: string) {
    return this.router.url.includes(route);
  }
}
```

In `app\app.component.html`:

```
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row my-3">
        <div *ngIf="!hasRoute('products/show/:id')" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <app-sidebar class="app-sidebar"></app-sidebar>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <app-footer class="app-footer"></app-footer>
</div>
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to understand, this solution fails, and the sidebar is displayed anywhere on the app.

##### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="notProductDetails()" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <app-sidebar class="app-sidebar"></app-sidebar>
</div>
```

HTML ^^^

```
constructor() {}
public notProductDetails(): void {
    return !window.location.pathname.startsWith('/products/show/');
}
```

TS

Simply use the window location to pull the pathname instead of injecting the router - remove the constructor injection. Also no need to pass in a prop value there, because you only have a single string you are asserting.

Comment: This code will work just one time, and generally isn't a best practice to use the `window` to retrieve the href

Comment: Here is the **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72308499/4512005)** I opted for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In that way, you are running that value just one time. In order to achieve this you can subscribe to the router events like this:

```js
public showBar: boolean = true;

constructor(private readonly router: Router) {
   this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(({ urlAfterRedirects }: NavigationEnd) =>
        this.showBar = this.hasRoute(urlAfterRedirects)
      );
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="showBar" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <app-sidebar class="app-sidebar"></app-sidebar>
</div>
```

In this way, you are updating the `showBar` value every time the navigation end.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone may find it useful, here is the final solutions I have applied to this problem:

In `app\app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'E-commerce';
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  routeIncludesNot(route: string) {
    return !window.location.pathname.startsWith(route);
  }
}
```

In `app\app.component.html` I have:

```
<div class="app-wrapper">
 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row my-3">
      <div *ngIf="routeIncludesNot('/products/show/')" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <app-sidebar class="app-sidebar"></app-sidebar>
      </div> 
      
      <div [ngClass]="routeIncludesNot('/products/show/') ? 'col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-9' : ''">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <app-footer class="app-footer"></app-footer>
</div>
```

See a "live demo" **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1yymn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.